# Doesn't aggregating time series sometimes throw away quantifiable uncertainty?

Tags: time-series, uncertainty, error-propagation

## Introduction

From time-to-time I hear a claim that it is better to forecast on [aggregated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) data because it is more "stable" or has less uncertainty.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/w2aops/comment/igq3aqp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) is an example, although I know I have encountered this claim in various other contexts.

> Aggregates are less volatile and more stable. Hence forecasting at an aggregate level would have a lower forecast error. If the company is OK with weekly granularity, that's the way to go.
>
> Conversely, if you forecast at a daily level and then aggregate, any bias in the daily level estimate will get compounded after aggregation.
>
> If day to day seasonality is important (ex: weekend vs weekdays) then daily level forecasts become necessary. For example if you want to forecast for a calendar month then # of weekdays vs weekends / holidays becomes important.

From my perspective a (univariate) time series data set is an instance of a stochastic process (i.e. a sequence of random variables). For example, if I were to do something like summation over an interval $I$

$$\sum_{t \in I} X_t$$

I would need to consider the [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables) which [propagates uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

## Examples

### Constant Random Variable

It is clear from a constant function such as $$f(X_1, \ldots, X_t) = 0$$ that it is possible for the probability over the image of a measurable function of a random variable to be degenerate (following a Dirac $\delta$ distribution). This exemplifies an aggregate function having less uncertainty in the output than the input when the input random variables are non-degenerate.

### Sum of Poisson Random Variables

There are plenty of counterexamples though. For example, the sum of a collection of independent Poisson variables is itself a Poisson variable with rate parameter equal to the sum of the respective rate parameters. I.e. suppose $$X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$$ for $$i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$$
then $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \text{Poisson} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \right).$$

Knowing the properties of a Poisson distribution, it is clear that the sum of the Poisson variables will have a greater variance than any of the individual Poisson variables we started with.

## Question

Am I missing something, or is aggregating time series not always going to result in a reduction of uncertainty resulting in merely ignoring quantifiable uncertainty?

Comment: A different approach is argued in [*Stop aggregating away the signal in your data*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/03/stop-aggregating-away-the-signal-in-your-data/), but they also state that aggregation is considered the standard best practice.

Comment: You implicitly assume that "aggregate" means the *sum* and that "volatility" is measured by the *variance.*  One can make sense of the quotation by avoiding those assumptions.

Comment: @whuber No, I used summation as a straightforward example. As per the link I supplied, on aggregation functions, many examples can be produced that are not the sum.

Comment: Yes, I did take variance as an example of what I understood to be volatility, but I am open to alternatives.

Comment: But that contradicts your "no," since the problem with the variance pertains to the sum and not to many other forms of aggregation.

Comment: @whuber Surely examples are permissible, and counterexamples are welcome.

Comment: Absolutely!  Your example suggests we might want to focus on adopting a generous interpretation of the quotation.    In so doing, I would like to suggest you would likely find the sense(s) in which it makes sense and is reasonable.

Comment: @whuber The generous interpretation that "there exists aggregation functions that reduce uncertainty" rather than "all aggregation functions reduce uncertainty"?

Comment: I guess one needs to be concrete. With daily data, it might be some cases where a major part of error is mis-recording the day. In such cases aggregations might pay ... but of course, it also depends on the intended use.

Comment: @whuber Thinking out loud... I already exemplified in the original question that some aggregation functions reduce uncertainty while others increase it. And in the comments I clarified that variance is just one choice of quantifying uncertainty. I guess I was thinking about full distributional inference whereas procedures such as rolling averages and exponential smoothing 'can' improve point estimates as evaluated by loss functions (e.g. mean squared error). Is this one of the senses you were alluding to?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Misrecording the day/date is definitely an interesting modelling challenge. I might try my luck with defining a mixture distribution over the missing days provided that there are not too many for a MCMC simulation to handle.