Using monthly data for yearly predictions
I need to predict a yearly quantity $y$ (water flowing into a reservoir). This is based on several factors, e.g. $x$ (amount of rain in the current year), and probably last years quantities (e.g., $lag(y)$).
In addition to the yearly data, I can also have finer resolution of the data, specifically monthly. My assumption is that more information is better. I still need yearly predictions though.
I'm not sure how can I compare the yearly models performance to the monthly ones. Even when predicting only 1 year ahead, this requires 12 steps into the future in the monthly models. This means I also need to predict 12 months of $x$, and if I'm using a lag variable - what do I do then? A rolling prediction (predicting each month then using it for predicting the next month)?
I wrote manual code to do this, and surprisingly (to me) the yearly models work much better. So, was my assumption incorrect, or should I recheck my code for bugs?
Moreover - is there a simple way to compare yearly and monthly predictions in R?

I feel like this question is related to something I would like to understand better: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642346/doesnt-aggregating-time-series-sometimes-throw-away-quantifiable-uncertainty
